# Preciso exportar uma variavel de um typescript para outro, porém a variavel nao obtem o valor que preciso

Tags: ionic, typescript, variáveis, exportação

preciso exportar a variável idioma de um ts para outro, porém, a variável (idioma) que esta sendo exportada não apresenta o valor que quero exportar.

tentei colocar o export em alguma linha dentro da mesma parte que a variavel, tambem tentei criar uma nova variavel para ser exportada que copia o valor da variavel que desejo exportar.

```
export class IdiomasPage implements OnInit {
  idioma = `br`;


  constructor() { 

  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }


  idiomabr(){
    this.idioma = `br`
    console.log(this.idioma)
  }

  idiomaus(){
    this.idioma = `us`
    console.log(this.idioma)
  }


}

export var idioma;
```

preciso que a variável idioma no export tenha o mesmo valor da variável idioma nas funções.

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar, Fábio. Primeiramente idioma é uma propriedade da classe IdiomasPage, não é definida no escopo que o export tem acesso, então ela deve estar retornando `undefined`. Você deveria retornar a classe e criar uma instância dela onde precisar chamar esse valor,.

Comment: obg, tentarei aplicar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar essa variável como um `observable` assim você poderá acessar o valor da variável em qualquer lugar da aplicação. 
Forneça esses métodos de acesso e troca de valor da variável por meio de um service.

primeiro crie o service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class IdiomasPageService {

// cria um novo behaviorSubject do tipo string.
private idiomaSubject = new BehaviorSubject<String>('br');

constructor() {}

// esse método retorna o subject onde você acessará o valor da sua variável idioma
getIdioma() {
    return this.idiomaSubject.asObservable();
}

emitNewValue(novoIdioma: string) {
    this.idiomaSubject.next(novoIdioma);
}

}
```

Depois na sua classe IdiomasPage pegue uma instância do objeto utilizando o service:

```
export class IdiomasPage implements OnInit {

private idioma = Observable<String>;

constructor(private idiomasPageService: IdiomasPageService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    //por padrão o primeiro valor de idioma é 'br', valor passado ao instanciar o behaviorSubject no serviço
    this.idioma = this.idiomasPageService.getIdioma();
}

alterarIdioma() {
    //alterando o valor de idioma na aplicação toda para 'pt' e depois 'en'
    this.idiomasPageService.emitNewValue('pt');
    this.idiomasPageService.emitNewValue('en');
}
```

}

---

agora em qualquer lugar da sua aplicação você poderá acessar e alterar o valor de idioma utilizando o serviço :).